# Angular2 how to watch a service property globally?

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I've been playing around with Angular2 for a few days now and I really like it so far. But I can't seem to wrap my head around something.

I have a class userService with 2 functions (I removed most logic.) that change the IsLoggedIn property:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService{
    public IsLoggedIn:bool = false

    login(){
        this.IsLoggedIn = true;
    }
    logout(){
        this.IsLoggedIn = false;
    }
}
```

I want to show and hide some elements in my global view depending on the IsLoggedIn property. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `Angular 2 rc.5`

**1** Provide the service in your `AppComponent` so it will be available as a singleton everywhere:

```
// https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#ngmodule-properties
@NgModule({
    imports: [...], 
    declarations: [...],
    providers: [UserService],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export default class AppModule {}
```

**2** In the component that needs access to the service, inject it, then use it

```
import {UserService}  from '...';
...
//inject service into the constructor
constructor(private userSvc:UserService){}
...
//to login
this.userSvc.login();
```

You can also access the service in that component's template

```
<div *ngIf="userSvc.isLoggedIn">Protected data </div>
```

**Addendum**:

If you want everything to update automatically when a user logs out, instead of referring to a boolean `userSvc.isLoggedIn`, refer to an object.

**UserService**

```
state = {
   loggedIn:false,
   ... //other states of the user (eg: permissions, preferences)
};

logout(){ this.state.loggedIn = false }
login() { this.state.loggedIn = true }
```

Then in your component's template

```
<div *ngIf="userSvc.state.loggedIn"> Protected data </div>
```

This works because all references are to the *same* `state` object in memory whereas in your original implementation, you *copied* the value of `isLoggedIn`. Remember: for this to work app-wide, only provide the service from your `AppModule`. Don't include it in the `providers` array of any other module or component.

Comment: Hi BeetleJuice, userSrv.IsLoggedIn doesn't get updated when someone clicks logout. I'm going to try it with Observables like Günter suggested. Thank you for you're answer!

Comment: @Mike Sure you can do that. A much simpler solution takes advantage of the fact that (1) Angular updates the app when values change natively (with its internal observables) and (2) objects are passed by reference in JavaScript.  Take a look at what I added to my answer.

Comment: @Mike you also need to make sure you don't skip step 1 in my answer. The service should be provided by the `AppModule` only. Don't include it in any other module's `providers` array. Otherwise you'll be running different instances of the service in parallel, with different states.

Comment: YES! That was the trick! Like you sad I was including the service in the providers array from other components. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you just inject the UserService into each component

```
constructor(public userService:UserService) {
}
```

where you wanna use it and bind it via

```
<div *ngIf="userService.IsLoggedIn">hello world</div>
```

Comment: Hi Oliver, Thank you for you're answer! When I use userService.IsLoggedIn in my views it doesn't get updated when someone clicks logout. I'm going to try it with Observables like Günter suggested.

Comment: hi mike, thanks for your answer. the clue is that you need to provide it in your app component and not in each single component. then all 3 provided solutions will work

Answer (score 0):

Inject the service to the components where you want to show/hide content depending on the `isLoggedIn` property

```
constructor(this.userService:UserService)
```

```
<div *ngIf="userService.IsLoggedIn">
  content when logged in
</div>
<div *ngIf="!userService.IsLoggedIn">
  content when not logged in
</div>
```

Even better would be an observable instead of a boolean. Observables are more efficient with change detection because they actively notify about changes.
For more details see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: userService.isLoggedIn isn't updateing in the view like this. Will an Observables do that?

Comment: Sure it is. Sounds like you provided the service multiple times and the component gets a new (different) instance than the one where you update the value. Angular DI creates a new instance per provider.

Comment: Ok, I will take a look at it. I'll keep you posted. Thanks Günter!